# HDF5 error while using Torch&lua: "unable to locate HDF5 header file at hdf5.h"

Tags: lua, hdf5, torch

I'm trying to run the neuraltalk2 code: it throws an error saying it is unable to find the hdf5 header file:

```
/home/jaysen/torch/install/bin/luajit: /home/jaysen/torch/install/share 
/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: /home/jaysen/torch/install/share/lua/5.1
/trepl    /init.lua:389: /home/jaysen/torch/install/share/lua/5.1
/hdf5/ffi.lua:42: Error: unable to locate HDF5 header file at hdf5.h


stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'error'
    /home/jaysen/torch/install/share/lua/5.1/trepl/init.lua:389: in function 'require'
    eval.lua:8: in main chunk
    [C]: in function 'dofile'
    ...ysen/torch/install/lib/luarocks/rocks/trepl/scm-1/bin/th:150: in main chunk
    [C]: at 0x55fce2035470
```

I'm running ubuntu.